# Split queue into train/test set

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, dataset, tensorflow-datasets

I set up my pipeline starting with a filename queue as in the following pseudocode:

```
filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(["file0.pd", "file1.pd"])
```

pointing to `TFRecords` containing multiple serialized `tf.train.Example` images. 
Following the tensorflow guide a function which reads one example:

```
def read_my_file_format(filename_queue):
  reader = tf.SomeReader()
  key, record_string = reader.read(filename_queue)
  example, label = tf.some_decoder(record_string)
  processed_example = some_processing(example)
  return processed_example, label
```

which is used for a batch queue:

```
def input_pipeline(filenames, batch_size):
  filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(filenames)
  example, label = read_my_file_format(filename_queue)

  example_batch, label_batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch(
      [example, label], batch_size=batch_size, capacity=100,
      min_after_dequeue=10)
  return example_batch, label_batch
```

I am looking for a way to split the data randomly into training and test sets. I don't want to save the training and test set into different files, but that the images are randomly assigned to the training or the test set independent of the file they are read from.
Ideally I would like to split the input pipeline into a training and test queue.

Here is what I normally do in numpy when I have to split a huge dataset

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import choice
from numpy.random import RandomState

queue = range(10)
weights = (.8,.2) # create 2 partitions with this weights

def sampler(partition, seed=0):
    rng = RandomState(seed)
    return lambda x: rng.choice(np.arange(len(weights)), p=weights) == partition

def split(queue, weights):
    # filter the queue for each partition
    return [filter(sampler(partition), queue) for partition in range(len(weights)) ]

(train, test) = split(queue, weights)               


print(list(train)) # [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9]
print(list(test))  # [7, 8]
```

Comment: Are you going to process each file more than once? If yes, splitting them into train and test sets randomly might be a problem.

Comment: Yes, since I sample a random patch from each image,

Comment: In that case you need to somehow remember what part of the file you designated as test and what part as training. It might be easier to do that right from the start, before even reading the files. Go through your file name list, read the meta data if your images are different size/shape and randomly decide which bits are going to test and which ones to train set. Store this information together with the file name in a dictionary or something and then feed the dictionary to the queue instead of just file names

Comment: use [`sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split()`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html)

Comment: In my experience, splitting data into train and test sets at run time has always proven to be a terrible idea.

Answer (score 3):

Suggestion, using Tensorflow Dataset API ([`map()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#map), [`interleave()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#interleave), [`filter()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#filter)):

```python
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

def _parse_function(example_proto):
    """ Parse TFRecord data """
    features = {"image": tf.FixedLenFeature((), tf.string, default_value=""),
              "label": tf.FixedLenFeature((), tf.int64, default_value=0)}
    parsed_features = tf.parse_single_example(example_proto, features)
    return parsed_features

def split_train_test(parsed_features, train_rate=0.8, seed=11):
    """ Randomly classify samples into training or testing split """
    # Snippet by Igor Gadelha Pereira (https://stackoverflow.com/a/49825457/624547)
    parsed_features['is_train'] = tf.gather(tf.random_uniform([1], seed=seed) < train_rate, 0)
    return parsed_features

def filter_per_split(parsed_features, train=True):
    """ Filter samples depending on their split """
    return parsed_features['is_train'] if train else ~parsed_features['is_train']

def select_features(parsed_features, keys=["image", "label"]):
    """ Return array of features selected by key """
    selected_features = [parsed_features[key] for key in keys]
    return selected_features

weights = (.8,.2)
num_files = 3
file_block_length = 1
files = ["/tmp/file{}.tfrecords".format(i) for i in range(num_files)]
# ... where file{i}.tfrecords contains:
# [{"label": i, "image": "class_{}/img_{}.png".format(i, k)} for k in range(10)]

# Create TFRecord file list list:
files = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(files)
# Interleave all records:
dataset = files.interleave(lambda x: tf.data.TFRecordDataset(x),
                           cycle_length=num_files, block_length=file_block_length)
# ^ dataset containing:
# [rec0@file0, rec0@file1, rec0@file2, rec1@file0, rec1@file1, rec1@file2, ...]

# Parse TFRecord samples:
dataset = dataset.map(_parse_function)

# Randomly classify samples between training or testing:
dataset = dataset.map(lambda x: split_train_test(x, train_rate=weights[0]))

# Split into 2 datasets accordingly:
dataset_train = dataset.filter(lambda x: filter_per_split(x, train=True))
dataset_test = dataset.filter(lambda x: filter_per_split(x, train=False))

# Opt. remove "is_train" key, keeping only the original features:
dataset_train = dataset_train.map(select_features)
dataset_test = dataset_test.map(select_features)

# Use:
iterator_train = dataset_train.make_one_shot_iterator()
iterator_test = dataset_test.make_one_shot_iterator()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    for it, name in zip([iterator_train, iterator_test], ["Training", "Testing"]):
        x = it.get_next()
        count = 0
        print("{} Split:".format(name))
        try:
            while True:
                print(sess.run(x))
                count += 1
        except:
            print("- End of Split ({} / {}".format(count, num_files * 10))
```

Output:

```python
Training Split:
(b'class_0/img_0.png', 0)
(b'class_1/img_0.png', 1)
(b'class_2/img_0.png', 2)
(b'class_0/img_1.png', 0)
(b'class_1/img_1.png', 1)
(b'class_1/img_2.png', 1)
(b'class_2/img_2.png', 2)
(b'class_0/img_3.png', 0)
(b'class_1/img_3.png', 1)
(b'class_2/img_3.png', 2)
(b'class_1/img_4.png', 1)
(b'class_2/img_4.png', 2)
(b'class_0/img_5.png', 0)
(b'class_1/img_5.png', 1)
(b'class_2/img_5.png', 2)
(b'class_0/img_6.png', 0)
(b'class_1/img_6.png', 1)
(b'class_2/img_6.png', 2)
(b'class_0/img_7.png', 0)
(b'class_1/img_7.png', 1)
(b'class_2/img_7.png', 2)
(b'class_0/img_8.png', 0)
(b'class_1/img_8.png', 1)
(b'class_2/img_8.png', 2)
(b'class_0/img_9.png', 0)
(b'class_1/img_9.png', 1)
(b'class_2/img_9.png', 2)
- End of Split (27 / 30
Testing Split:
(b'class_2/img_1.png', 2)
(b'class_0/img_2.png', 0)
(b'class_0/img_4.png', 0)
- End of Split (3 / 30
```