# Is there a way to partition a tf.Dataset with TensorFlow’s Dataset API?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I checked [the doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset) but I could not find a method for it. I want to de cross validation, so I kind of need it.

Note that I'm not asking how to split a tensor, as I know that TensorFlow provides an API for that an has been answered in another question. I'm asking on how to partition a tf.Dataset (which is an abstraction).

Comment: I posted my answer over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58452268/5462608). I think it better answers your question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split a dataset created by Tensorflow dataset API in to Train and Test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48213766/split-a-dataset-created-by-tensorflow-dataset-api-in-to-train-and-test)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either:

1) Use the [shard](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.12/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#shard) transformation partition the dataset into multiple "shards". Note that for best performance, sharding should be to data sources (e.g. filenames).

2) As of TensorFlow 1.12, you can also use the [window](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.12/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#window) transformation to build a dataset of datasets.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid you cannot. The dataset API is a way to efficiently stream inputs to your net at run time. It is not a set of tools to manipulate datasets as a whole -- in that regards it might be a bit of a misnomer.

Also, if you could, this would probably be a bad idea. You would rather have this train/test split done once and for all.

- it let you review those sets offline
- if the split is done each time you run an experiment there is a risk that samples start swapping sets if you are not extremely careful (e.g. when you add more data to your existing dataset)

See also a related question about [how to split a set into training & testing in tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41859605/split-inputs-into-training-and-test-sets).

Comment: I believe that splitting the data is necessary for cross validation. I suppose one could partition it only once in many chunks...