# How to split a tensorflow dataset into train, test and validation in a Python script?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, train-test-split

On a jupyter notebook with Tensorflow-2.0.0, a train-validation-test split of 80-10-10 was performed in this way:

```
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
from os import getcwd
splits = tfds.Split.ALL.subsplit(weighted=(80, 10, 10))

filePath = f"{getcwd()}/../tmp2/"
splits, info = tfds.load('fashion_mnist', with_info=True, as_supervised=True, split=splits, data_dir=filePath)
```

However, when trying to run the same code locally I get the error

```
AttributeError: type object 'Split' has no attribute 'ALL'
```

I have seen I can create two sets in this way:

```
splits, info = tfds.load('fashion_mnist', with_info=True, as_supervised=True, split=['train[:80]','test[80:90]'], data_dir=filePath)
```

but I do not know how I can add a third set.

Answer (score 4):

`tfds.Split.ALL.subsplit` or `tfds.Split.TRAIN.subsplit` apparently are deprecated and no longer supported.

Some of the datasets are already split between train and test. In this case I found the following solution (using for example the fashion MNIST dataset):

```
splits, info = tfds.load('fashion_mnist', with_info=True, as_supervised=True,
split=['train+test[:80]','train+test[80:90]', 'train+test[90:]'],
data_dir=filePath)
(train_examples, validation_examples, test_examples) = splits
```

**EDIT AFTER COMMENTS**

The previous code had some errors. First of all, this [official link](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/splits) says:

> Full dataset ('all'): 'all' is a special split name corresponding to the union of all splits (equivalent to 'train+test+...')

but when I tried it did not work. `all` would be helpful but there is an alternative.
The error in the previous code is that the `%` must be used and that it must be specified for each set. I modified the code in this way:

```
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
splits, info = tfds.load('fashion_mnist', with_info=True, as_supervised=True,
split=['train[:80%]+test[:80%]','train[80%:90%]+test[80%:90%]', 'train[90%:]+test[90%:]'],
data_dir='./')
#(train_examples, validation_examples, test_examples) = splits

for el in splits:
    print(el.cardinality())
```

which prints:

```
tf.Tensor(56000, shape=(), dtype=int64)
tf.Tensor(7000, shape=(), dtype=int64)
tf.Tensor(7000, shape=(), dtype=int64)
```

Comment: This doesn't really work. 'train+test[:80]' for example takes the 100% of train and the 80% of test; it does't take 80% of the combined train + test.

Comment: Moreover if you don't add % you are not going to use percentage split (so in your case you are taking the whole train example plus the first 80 example in the test as train example.

Comment: I removed the downvote, and I upvoted you:) Thank you for addressing the issue. I can confirm that the 'all' special split name doesn't work (I checked the github code, and they revoked the push request). So for now I guess the flag 'all' it's only present in the documentation but not in the code itself.

Answer (score -1):

In the case of rock_paper_scissor dataset on tfds it works for me:

```
splits = ['train+test[:80]', 'train+test[80:90]', 'train+test[90:]']

splits, info = tfds.load( 'rock_paper_scissors', split=splits, as_supervised=True, with_info=True)

(train_examples, validation_examples, test_examples) = splits

num_examples = info.splits['train'].num_examples
num_classes = info.features['label'].num_classes
```

Comment: @Francesco Boi please check this answer.

Comment: @Nikita I can't see what additional information this answer has compared to my older one.