# How to perform sklearn style train-test split on feature and label tensors using built in tensorflow methods?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, train-test-split

Reposting my [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63764194/11542679) since even after significant improvements to clarity, it was not revived by the community.

I am looking for a way to split feature and corresponding label data into train and test using TensorFlow inbuilt methods. My data is already in two tensors (i.e. `tf.Tensor` objects), named `features` and `labels`.

I know how to do this easily for numpy arrays using `sklearn.model_selection` as shown in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18544946/11542679). Additionally, I was pointed to this [method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41862548/11542679) which requires the data to be in a single tensor. Also, I need the train and test sets to be disjoint, unlike in this [method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51126863/11542679) (meaning they can't have common data points after the split).

I am looking for a way to do the same using built-in methods in Tensorflow.

There may be too many conditions in my requirement, but basically what is needed is an equivalent method to `sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split()` in Tensorflow such as the below:

```
import tensorflow as tf

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = tf.train_test_split(features,
                                                labels,
                                                test_size=0.1,
                                                random_state=123)
```

Comment: Did my answer help you @Hawklaz?

Comment: Yes, thank you. I was hoping for a direct function to do it similar to how it's done in sklearn. But this works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by using TF in the following way

```py
from typing import Tuple

import tensorflow as tf


def split_train_test(features: tf.Tensor,
                     labels: tf.Tensor,
                     test_size: float,
                     random_state: int = 1729) -> Tuple[tf.Tensor, tf.Tensor, tf.Tensor, tf.Tensor]:

    # Generate random masks
    random = tf.random.uniform(shape=(tf.shape(features)[0],), seed=random_state)
    train_mask = random >= test_size
    test_mask = random < test_size

    # Gather values
    train_features, train_labels = tf.boolean_mask(features, mask=train_mask), tf.boolean_mask(labels, mask=train_mask)
    test_features, test_labels = tf.boolean_mask(features, mask=test_mask), tf.boolean_mask(labels, mask=test_mask)

    return train_features, test_features, train_labels, test_labels
```

What we are doing here is first creating a random uniform tensor with the size of the length of the data.
Then we follow by creating boolean masks according to the ratio given by `test_size` and finally we extract the relevant part for train/test using [`tf.boolean_mask`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/boolean_mask)